# The getter did was called on null even though I have a catch block

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

The error I am receiving: Exception has occurred.
NoSuchMethodError (NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'uid' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: uid)

```html
@override
  AuthenticationState get initialState => Uninitialized();

  @override
  Stream<AuthenticationState> mapEventToState(
    AuthenticationEvent event,
  ) async* {
    if (event is AppStarted) {
      yield* _mapAppStartedToState();
    } else if (event is LoggedIn) {
      yield* _mapLoggedInToState();
    } else if (event is LoggedOut) {
      yield* _mapLoggedOutToState();
    }
  }

  Stream<AuthenticationState> _mapAppStartedToState() async* {
    
    try {
      final isSignedIn = await _userRepository.isSignedIn();
      if (isSignedIn) {
        final uid = await _userRepository.getUser();
        final isFirstTime = await _userRepository.isFirstTime(uid);

        if (!isFirstTime) {
          yield AuthenticatedButNotSet(uid);
        } else {
          yield Authenticated(uid);
        }
      } else {
        yield Unauthenticated();
      }
    } catch (_) {
      yield Unauthenticated();
    }
  }
```

The error is happening when I call getUser, but im not sure why because I included a catch block that yields Unauthenticated

```html
  Future<String> getUser() async {
    return (await _firebaseAuth.currentUser()).uid;
  }
```

Comment: `await _firebaseAuth.currentUser()` is null.

Comment: I know but how do I catch that error? because I restarted my app and no user is logged in so I am unable to start my actual app